# How to group rows into two groups in sql?

Tags: sql, group-by

Lets say I have such a table:

```
id|time|operation
1  2      read
2  5      write
3  3      read
4  7      read
5  2      save
6  1      open
```

and now I would like to do two things:

1. Divide all these records into two groups:
   1) all rows where operation equals to "read"
   2) all other rows.
2. Sum the time in each group.

So that my query would result only into two rows.

What I got so far is:

```
select 
 sum(time) as total_time,
 operation
group by
 operation
;
```

Although that gives me many groups, depending on the number of distinct operations.

How I could group them only into two categories?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`group by` can take arbitrary clauses, so

```
GROUP BY (operation = 'read')
```

will work. Essentially you'd be grouping on the boolean result of the comparison, not the value of the operation field, so any record which is "read" will be group `1`, and any non-read will be group `0`.

Comment: `group by case when operation='real' then 1 else 0 end` kinda works around that, but then you're stuck with having to use aggregates on everything

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works very well. There is only one thing I would like to improve. Is it possible to change the value of operation in group that is different than 'read'? So that I would have as a result for example: [newline]
total_time operation [newline]
267 others [newline]
120 read [newline]

Comment: `group by (operation = 'read'), operation`. That'll split the reads into their own group, and still group everything else into their own individual ones.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can also use a `case` statement:

```
select
case when operation != 'read' then 'other'
  else operation end as operation
,sum(time) as total_time
from table
group by case when operation != 'read' then 'other'
  else operation end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT T.op, sum(T.time)
FROM ( SELECT time, CASE operation 
                WHEN 'read' THEN 'read' ELSE 'not read' END AS op ) T
GROUP BY T.op
```